# Is there a general method for calculating the end of an animation and switching between animations when they are finished?

Tags: java, algorithm, animation, libgdx

I'm working on a game that has animations with non uniform key frames so that things like start up, active, and recovery frames can be changed for balance purposes. I have looping animations such as idle and walking that loop fairly smoothly however attacking animations that only play once are very stuttery and sometimes play multiple times.

I've tried the following calculations to no help in pseudo ish code

```
in animation class:
isAnimationFinished(float time)
    return (time / animationLength) >= 0.95
    // Note: 0.95 seemed like a good value as it seemed that the last frame in any animation
    // would result in a value between 0.95 and 0.99 when used in this calculation. 

// frameTimes is an array of floats that stores the amount of time, in milliseconds,
// that a key frame should be drawn for. 
// One example of an array used is:
float[] jabFrames = {
    FRAME * frameData[0].getStartUpFrames(), FRAME * frameData[0].getActiveFrames(),
    FRAME * frameData[0].getRecoveryFrames()
};
// Where FRAME is a float of 1/60f and frameData is an int array

getAnimationDuration()
    sum = 0.0
    for each floatValue in frameTimes:
        sum += floatValue 
    return sum

...

in the pawn class's draw function:

draw(deltaTime):
    stateTime += deltaTime (time since last render)

    get the animation based on the animation_state

    if(animation_state is JAB and animation.isAnimationFinished(stateTime))
        animation_state = IDLE

    if(stateTime >= animation.getAnimationDuration())
        stateTime -= animation.getAnimationDuration()

    drawAnimation()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [Animation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Animation.html#getAnimationDuration--) class from libGDX you can use these methods (from the API):

- [getAnimationDuration](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Animation.html#getAnimationDuration--): the duration of the entire animation, number of frames times frame duration, in seconds
- [isAnimationFinished(float)](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Animation.html#isAnimationFinished-float-): Whether the animation would be finished if played without looping (PlayMode#NORMAL), given the state time.

So all you need to know is the current `stateTime`, that is calculated like you already have done in you pseudocode:

```
public void draw(float deltaTime) {
    stateTime += deltaTime;
    
    //...
}
```

For a further introduction on how to use the libGDX animations, see [this tutorial](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation).

---

In one of my projects I use a wrapper class for some additional functionality. If you want to use it you can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/tfassbender/DwarfScrollerGDX/blob/master/core/src/net/jfabricationgames/gdx/animation/AnimationDirector.java), or use the current version of it:

**AnimationDirector**

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation.PlayMode;

import net.jfabricationgames.gdx.screens.game.GameScreen;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;

public class AnimationDirector<T extends TextureRegion> {
    
    public static boolean isTextureRight(boolean initialAnimationDirectionIsRight, AnimationDirector<TextureRegion> animation) {
        return initialAnimationDirectionIsRight != animation.getKeyFrame().isFlipX();
    }
    
    public static boolean isTextureLeft(boolean initialAnimationDirectionIsRight, AnimationDirector<TextureRegion> animation) {
        return initialAnimationDirectionIsRight == animation.getKeyFrame().isFlipX();
    }
    
    private float stateTime;
    private Animation<T> animation;
    
    private AnimationSpriteConfig spriteConfig;
    
    public AnimationDirector(Animation<T> animation) {
        this.animation = animation;
        initializeSpriteConfigWithoutPosition();
    }
    
    protected void initializeSpriteConfigWithoutPosition() {
        T keyFrame = animation.getKeyFrame(0);
        spriteConfig = new AnimationSpriteConfig().setWidth(keyFrame.getRegionWidth()).setHeight(keyFrame.getRegionHeight());
    }
    
    /**
     * Draw the current key frame of this animation onto the {@link SpriteBatch}.<br>
     * ATTENTION: This method will throw an {@link IllegalStateException} if this AnimationDirector does not contain an AnimationSpriteConfig object.
     */
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
        if (spriteConfig == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No AnimationSpriteConfig. Please add an AnimationSpriteConfig in order to use the draw method");
        }
        T keyFrame = getKeyFrame();
        float x = spriteConfig.x + ((spriteConfig.width - keyFrame.getRegionWidth()) * GameScreen.WORLD_TO_SCREEN * 0.5f);
        float y = spriteConfig.y + ((spriteConfig.height - keyFrame.getRegionHeight()) * GameScreen.WORLD_TO_SCREEN * 0.5f);
        batch.draw(keyFrame, x, y, spriteConfig.width * 0.5f, spriteConfig.height * 0.5f, keyFrame.getRegionWidth(), keyFrame.getRegionHeight(),
                GameScreen.WORLD_TO_SCREEN, GameScreen.WORLD_TO_SCREEN, 0f);
    }
    
    public void drawInMenu(SpriteBatch batch) {
        if (spriteConfig == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No AnimationSpriteConfig. Please add an AnimationSpriteConfig in order to use the draw method");
        }
        
        T keyFrame = getKeyFrame();
        batch.draw(keyFrame, spriteConfig.x, spriteConfig.y, spriteConfig.width, spriteConfig.height);
    }
    
    /**
     * Get the frame at the current time.
     */
    public T getKeyFrame() {
        return animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime);
    }
    
    public float getStateTime() {
        return stateTime;
    }
    
    public void increaseStateTime(float delta) {
        stateTime += delta;
    }
    
    public void setStateTime(float stateTime) {
        this.stateTime = stateTime;
    }
    
    /**
     * Reset the state time to 0 to restart the animation.
     */
    public void resetStateTime() {
        stateTime = 0;
    }
    
    /**
     * Set the animation state time to the end of the animation.
     */
    public void endAnimation() {
        stateTime = animation.getAnimationDuration();
    }
    
    public void setPlayMode(PlayMode playMode) {
        animation.setPlayMode(playMode);
    }
    
    /**
     * Get the {@link Animation} that this object holds.
     */
    public Animation<T> getAnimation() {
        return animation;
    }
    
    public boolean isAnimationFinished() {
        return animation.isAnimationFinished(stateTime);
    }
    
    public float getAnimationDuration() {
        return animation.getAnimationDuration();
    }
    
    /**
     * Flip all key frames of the animation.
     */
    public void flip(boolean x, boolean y) {
        for (TextureRegion region : animation.getKeyFrames()) {
            region.flip(x, y);
        }
    }
    
    public AnimationSpriteConfig getSpriteConfig() {
        return spriteConfig;
    }
    
    public void setSpriteConfig(AnimationSpriteConfig spriteConfig) {
        this.spriteConfig = spriteConfig;
    }
    
    public AnimationSpriteConfig getSpriteConfigCopy() {
        return new AnimationSpriteConfig(spriteConfig);
    }
}
```

**AnimationSpriteConfig**

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;

public class AnimationSpriteConfig {
    
    public static AnimationSpriteConfig fromSprite(Sprite sprite) {
        AnimationSpriteConfig spriteConfig = new AnimationSpriteConfig();
        spriteConfig.width = sprite.getWidth();
        spriteConfig.height = sprite.getHeight();
        spriteConfig.x = sprite.getX();
        spriteConfig.y = sprite.getY();
        
        return spriteConfig;
    }
    
    public AnimationSpriteConfig() {}
    
    public AnimationSpriteConfig(AnimationSpriteConfig spriteConfig) {
        this.x = spriteConfig.x;
        this.y = spriteConfig.y;
        this.width = spriteConfig.width;
        this.height = spriteConfig.height;
    }
    
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float width;
    public float height;
    
    public AnimationSpriteConfig setX(float x) {
        this.x = x;
        return this;
    }
    
    public AnimationSpriteConfig setY(float y) {
        this.y = y;
        return this;
    }
    
    public AnimationSpriteConfig setWidth(float width) {
        this.width = width;
        return this;
    }
    
    public AnimationSpriteConfig setHeight(float height) {
        this.height = height;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: libgdx default animation class doesn't allow for uneven key frame lengths afaik. isAnimationFinished(float) uses a single value for frame duration that is passed into the constructor. It calculates the frame number by : frameNumber = (int)(stateTime / frameDuration);. and then depending on the on the play mode adjusts the framenumber accordingly. Some of my key frames need to play for 4 frames then 5 frames. which again for looping animations is fine but for attacking single play animations I'm having trouble getting the single animation to play smoothly